# How rules work on Odoo v8?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8, rule

I made a module in Odoo v8. One of the things my module does is adding a boolean field named **is_important** to the model *res.partner*.

As you probably know, the users groups in sales are, less privileges first, more privileges last:
**group_sale_salesman**, **group_sale_salesman_all_leads**, **group_sale_manager**. Then, I had to add some rules to my module:

- Users who belong to the group **group_sale_salesman** didn't have to
  see the partners whose field **is_important** was *True*, nor
  partners who were from a different state.
- Users who belong to the group **group_sale_salesman_all_leads**
  didn't have to see the partners whose field **is_important** was
  *True*.

So I implemented the following XML code:

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="res_partner_same_state_no_important_rule">
    <field name="name">res_partner: read only no important partners from your state</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_partner"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('state_id.id', '=', user.state_id.id), ('is_important', '=', False)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_sale_salesman'))]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
</record>

<record model="ir.rule" id="res_partner_no_important_rule">
    <field name="name">res_partner: read only no important partners</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_partner"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('is_important', '=', False)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_sale_salesman_all_leads'))]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
</record>
```

It seemed to work great, but then, I logged in with an user who belonged to the group **group_sale_manager**, and the rule named **res_partner_no_important_rule** was affecting it (despite not declaring a rule for that group).

It's like the group was inheriting the least restrictive rules of the groups which less privileges. Is this true? Am I right?

Finally, I had to add a nonsense rule to fix this and allow users who belong to **group_sale_manager** to keep the privileges they had before I implemented my other rules (read, write, create and unlink to True):

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="res_partner_see_all">
    <field name="name">res_partner: read all</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_partner"/>
    <field name="domain_force">['|', ('is_important', '=', True), ('is_important', '=', False)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_sale_manager'))]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
</record>
```

After implementing this last rule, it started to work. But, is there any better way to achieve what I wanted?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

group_sale_manager has group_sale_salesman_all_leads in its implied groups, so a member of group_sale_manager is automatically added to group_sale_salesman_all_leads and thus the rule applies to him. If no other rule give him access to those partners, he won't have access to them.

You can replace the domain_force of the last rule by [(1, '=', 1)].
I think there is no better way.